# What selenium screenshot would be captured on remote jenkins server if two users are logged in simultaneously?

Tags: selenium, jenkins, remote-access, webpage-screenshot

My selenium code is on remote server, i will be executing that through Jenkins. Max 2 people can login to remote server at same time. I have used Robot class in my code to capture screenshot of alert message window as it is not possible with class TakeScreenshot. If during execution, another user has logged simultaneously then while capturing screenshot(using Robot class),then will it capture this screenshot of this other user's activity?If it does then how do I handle it?

Comment: Whichever user is logged in to the driver that the screenshot is taken on?

Comment: The thing with Robot class is it'll take a screenshot of whatever process/window is live on the screen at the moment. So even if I am logged into the driver, my concern is when another user has logged in simultaneously, would that capture the other's user's screen activity??